# sshpass some windows and run a network bat

Tags: windows, bash, shell, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a bash script to sshpass Windows and run a network shared bat. The problem is that when I run the command

```
\\server_name\shared_folder\xx.bat
```

via cmd it is ok, but when I write it in shell script, I get the error

> bin/sh: server_nameshared_folderxx.bat: command not found

It seems I do not write the path with correct style.
should I using more `\` for the command in the script? Just like this?

```
\\\\server_name\\\shared_folder\\\xx.bat
```

sh Code:

```
copy_files(){
    sshpass -p Sybase123 ssh -o StrictHostKeychecking=no root@$machine "\\server_name\shared_folder\xx.bat"
    echo "-- Finished action on $machine!"
}

for machine in `cat $machine_file`
do
    echo "$machine:"
    copy_files $machine;
done
```

Comment: I don't think `bash` on the target system can use paths like `\\server_name\shared_folder\xx.bat`. For cygwin, [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/102233/how-to-go-to-remote-directory-in-cygwin) _may_ help.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I forget to say windows has Cygwin, so It works as you sugguest, thank you very much.BTW: I sign up today for asking this problem,this is my first ask, I love stackoverflow, I love you for helping.

Comment: `Windows + bash` can be 2 cases - `ubuntu bash on win10`, `cygwin/msys on windows`. So, I was not sure which case you were using...